# aar with jar contains images, how to access images?

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, jar, aar

we have a aar files what contains jar in libs folder.
Jar contains images in images/ folder

Then we want to access to images (class inside jar).

```
InputStream xButtonStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/x.png");
```

What is working correct when we are using single alone jar. When we want to use aar, there is a problem. Android and unity3d are not finding png files.

Can you help us to get into images somehow? Maybe directory is different then? I don't know what to do, project is for yesterday.

Structure

1. aar
2. jar
3. images and java class inside jar

Comment: I'd suggest looking into your AAR to see if the images are actually where you expect. There should not be a different in the class structure in the AAR. Note that the correct way, if you are using an AAR, is to load the resources as a drawable, since an AAR can contain Android resources like strings, layouts, drawables, etc.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman so If I put resoursces as a drawables in aar, It will be no difference for class inside jar? Classes will merge at one level, aar?

Comment: If you organize your assets per Android, it won't change how you reference your classes. I think that's what you asked. It will of course change how to reference your assets.

Comment: I haven't added any jar file in my libraries, but when I need to use any class or resource from dependencies inside my library I have to add `transitive=true` in my gradle file in my app module, maybe that could help